# Help with accuracy: The first payment will be made in exactly one month. The effective annual rate of interest is 8 %. Determine the value of X

Tags: actuarial-science

Betty received $ 500,000 from a life insurance policy to be distributed to her as an annuity certain in 10 equal annual installments with the first payment made immediately. On the day she receives her third payment, she is offered a monthly perpetuity of X in lieu of the future annual payments. The first payment will be made in exactly one month. The effective annual rate of interest is 8 %. Determine the value of X

I'm struggling to get an accurate figure for this question for the value of X. I'm just doing practise  questions for my CT1 exam and if I had the figure I have to work towards I'd figure out my error!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos How would I do that ? Is it possible to upload a photo of your work?

Comment: Yes, you can upload images, but I suggest that you type your texts.

Answer (score 0):

The annual installment is $P$ such that 
$$
500,000=P\times \ddot a_{\overline{10}|8\%}
$$
that is $P\approx 68,995.13$.

The present value of the future payments after the 3rd payment is $P\times \ddot a_{\overline{7}|8\%}\approx 387,951.31$.

The effective monthly rate is $i=(1.08)^{1/12}-1\approx 0.6434\%$ and then
$$
387,951.31=\frac{X}{i}
$$
that is $X\approx 2,496.09$

Comment: Thank you for helping but I don't think this answer is correct!

Comment: @IanWalter Why not? Do you have anorher value?